# Sum nr of sales on a typical article number SQL

Tags: sql, sum

it's pretty simple i guess but i can't get it to work.

I have a Sales table with theese columns
Date,Artnr,Amount

For example

```
20150326, 19929, 2
20150326, 10231, 1
20150326, 10001, 3
20150325, 19929, 4
```

Now i want to make a SQL that gives me the Artnr and the sum Amount back.So in the example above i sold 6 artnr 19929 at two different times. Now i want to sum the amount on the rows with the same artnr and add them togheter. Like this.

```
10231, 1
10001, 3
19929, 6
```

The closest i get is with this SQL

```
SELECT a.artnr (SELECT SUM(b.amount) FROM SALES b WHERE b.artnr = a.artnr)
FROM SALES a
```

My Problem here is that i still get all rows back but at least it gives me the right sum amount.

```
19929, 6
10231, 1
10001, 3
19929, 6
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `group by`:

```
SELECT artnr, SUM(amount) 
FROM SALES s
GROUP BY artnr;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, should have know that. Long day